# HTTP connection

Tags: vb.net

How can i make http Connection in vb.net?

what is the method call used ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes.